# PHP function str_replace should be placed where in the MVC?

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, str-replace

Where would I use the PHP str_replace function to convert '¶' into < br > or \n?

I tried looking at related posts about [**how to use str_replace**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459210/how-to-str-replace-a-section-of-php-code?rq=1) and [**how to convert ¶ to \n in PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693033/how-can-i-convert-pilcrow-to-n-in-php-after-reading-a-record-from-mysql). I also tried adding the str_replace in the model rather than in the query.

**WinnerStatement**

> "Hello¶¶, I am a winner"

**Model**

```
public function early_results($user_id) { 
    $sql = " 
        SELECT 
            l.winnerStatement AS WinnerStatement,
            l.recipient AS Recipient, 
        FROM Letter l
        WHERE 
            l.winnerId = '{$this->db->escape($user_id)}';";
    return $this->db->query($sql)->result();  
}
```

**View**

```
<td><?=$feed_item->WinnerStatement?></td>
```

**Controller**

```
$this->load->view('dashboard/snippet/winners', array('WinnerStatement' => $winner_statement));
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `<td><?php echo str_replace( '¶', '<br />', $feed_item->WinnerStatement ); ?></td>`

Comment: can be in the query `REPLACE(l.winnerStatement, '¶', '<br>') AS ...`

Comment: Maybe it's better to fix it in controller, so the view is not messed up with string manipulation codes...

Comment: Is there any difference in setting it in the view rather than how @Deadooshka suggested in the query?

Comment: You could use mysql `replace` to make the replacement in the query if you wanted to but the question did ask about the php function `str_replace` - hence code given in comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set it in view

```
<td><?=str_replace('¶', '<br />', $feed_item->WinnerStatement)?></td>
```